# How to SET ReportParameter Value of SSRS Report in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to Call SSRS Report in WPF with Parameter Passing From WPF UI without using Microsoft Report Viewer Component. I Used the following Code for Passing Parameter to SSRS Report...

```
            Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[] reportParameterCollection = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[1];       //Array size describes the number of paramaters.

            reportParameterCollection[0] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter();
            reportParameterCollection[0].Name = "OfficeCode";
            reportParameterCollection[0].Values.Add(cmbOfficeName.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim());
            rpt.SetParameters(reportParameterCollection);
```

But, the Last Statement...

```
rpt.SetParameters(reportParameterCollection);
```

raise the following error...

> The Best Overload method match for 'Microsoft.reporting.Winform.Report.Setparameters(Microsoft.Reporting.Winform.ReportParameter)' has Some Invalid Argument.

How Can I Solve this issue? Can Anyone help Me.? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SetParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252146.aspx) method requires an [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx), not an array as you have